# Angular load selectlist with json from mvc controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Here is my view:

```
  <div>
     <select ng-model="firstSupplier" ng-options="firstSupplier as firstSupplier.SupplierName for firstSupplier in jsonSuppliers"></select>
  </div>
```

and here is my angular controller:

(function() {
    var app = angular.module("CustCMS");

```
var indexController = function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/Home/GetAllSuppliers")
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    $scope.jsonSuppliers = response.data;
                                    $scope.firstSupplier = $scope.jsonSuppliers[0];
                                });




};

app.controller("IndexController", ["$scope", "$http", indexController]);
```

}());

and here is my mvc controller:

```
   public JsonResult GetAllSuppliers()
    {
        var suppliers = GetAll();
        return Json(new { data = suppliers}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here is the json that returns to the angular controller jsonSuppliers:

```
    {"data":[{"SupplierId":1,"SupplierName":"Normstahl","PrefixCountryCode":"NS01COUNTRY","UseOrderSystem":false,"IsDirect":false,"Customers":[]},{"SupplierId":2,"SupplierName":"TestSupplier 2","PrefixCountryCode":null,"UseOrderSystem":false,"IsDirect":false,"Customers":[]},{"SupplierId":3,"SupplierName":"Ditec","PrefixCountryCode":"DIIT01COUNTRY","UseOrderSystem":false,"IsDirect":false,"Customers":[]},{"SupplierId":4,"SupplierName":"Ospf","PrefixCountryCode":"CRCOUNTRY","UseOrderSystem":false,"IsDirect":false,"Customers":[]},{"SupplierId":5,"SupplierName":"Alsta","PrefixCountryCode":null,"UseOrderSystem":false,"IsDirect":false,"Customers":[]}]}
```

Is where something that im missing here? 
I don't get any errors in the console....
Is there an easier way to do it that would be much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't return `response.data` but assign it to `$scope.jsonSuppliers` in your promise callback. And the same with `$scope.firstSupplier` - which needs to be set after receiving the data from the server.

Comment: Thanks! I changed my controller but i still get undefined as suppliername.

Comment: Ok, your server call looks ok now. I guess you must have an error in your [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). You could try using a simple ng-repeat to render the different options. Or you could try `supplier.SupplierName for supplier in jsonSuppliers track by supplier.SupplierId` in the ng-options.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it with you response and that my json from my mvc controller is data so i had to do response.data.data